# Convert a list of multiple tuples, each consisting of a str and a dict into a json file as output

Tags: python, json, tuples, spacy

I have a list of tuples of size 2. There are 100 tuples. each tuple has a str and a dict element. I want to save this list in json format:
Sample data:

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "PERSON")]}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC")]}),
]
```

Presently each string inside the tuple is a text document with multiple lines. I want a list of tuples as output of the json file

Comment: how do you want your output to look like

Comment: Same as in the TRAIN_DATA list. Only there should be a newline after each tuple and shouldnot be all tuples in one row. And the output should be saved to a json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json.dumps` to get a json string as output.

```
import json
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "PERSON")]}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC")]}),
]
print json.dumps(TRAIN_DATA)
```

Output:

```
[["Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [[7, 17, "PERSON"]]}], ["I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [[7, 13, "LOC"], [18, 24, "LOC"]]}]]
```

You can similarly use `json.loads()` to load a json string in a python list

Example

```
json.loads('[["Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [[7, 17, "PERSON"]]}], ["I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [[7, 13, "LOC"], [18, 24, "LOC"]]}]]')
```

Comment: I want to output this to a json file. Also, it should all be not in one row but how the TRAIN_DATA is, so it has to have a newline for each tuple and output it to a json file.

Comment: You can use json.dump instead of dumps to write to a file. Regarding formatting,  you can use the indent parameter

```print json.dumps(TRAIN_DATA, indent=4)```

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(TRAIN_DATA, outfile)
```